# Is there a good way to make a composting watering tank that won't clog 1/16th inch holes?

Tags: plumbing-fixture, gardening

I'm looking at building a hose attachment (chamber) that I can stuff with comfrey leaves, and some good compost to fertilize my garden some (force water through a pipe with small holes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOpvLFwjS1g), but not clog my watering stick (PVC pipe with lots of holes to distribute water pressure). How can I make a chamber that will prevent pipe clogging with hardware supply equipment? Is this even possible?

Comment: Is this like a hose end sprayer? Or something that size?  I doubt compost has enough dissolvable nitrogen for this to be real beneficial.  There are products on the market where you put concentrated fertilizer in a hose end sprayer and water with it.  Like this one: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06Y3HMXHV/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_i_mU3dBbK6ZPF2W

Comment: yes, something like that, or is my best bet to buy one of those that were used already, because it has to attach to another hose?

Comment: Just get one of those. Yesterday at home depot that same item I linked was on sale for 9.99 (I’m sure prices vary around the country so that no guarantee).

Comment: it's a sprayer, not a hose attachment though

Comment: What I linked is hose attached and a sprayer. It dissolves crystallized fertilizers such as miracle grow and mixes it into the water.

Comment: so it attached to a hose on both ends? did it really?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called compost tea. The compost is placed in a barrel of water and aerated, then the solids are filtered out. The resulting water can be used in an agricultural sprayer to fertilize fields. Harvard uses and promotes it extensively if you're looking for more information.

At home sized scales you can use aquarium pumps and aerators, along with pantyhose filters.

Comment: My cousin does extensive vegetable gardening and swears by compost tea. It's important to note that the extraction and distribution process are normally separated. (1) Compost vegetative waste, (2) separate liquid from solids, (3) spray the liquid on garden soil.

Comment: i'm wanting to build one right onto the hose though, most compost tea is made in buckets.